# Remote backup with MEB (MySQL Enterprise Backup)

Tags: mysql, backup

I am trying to create a routine to backup a remote instance. The command I'm using is:

```
mysqlbackup --user=user --password --host=192.168.0.109 --port=3308 --backup-image="D:\test.mbi" --force --backup-dir=d:\backups_temp\ --force backup-to-image
```

But MEB returns the following error:

> 150910 14:50:53 mysqlbackup: INFO: MEB logfile created at d:\backups_temp\meta\MEB_2015-09-10.14-50-53_image_backup.log
>
> mysqlbackup: ERROR: innodb_page_size obtained from innodb file header 0 is not matching with innodb_page_size 16384 which is read from backup configurations. 
>   mysqlbackup: ERROR: Mismatch found in innodb_page_size.
>
> mysqlbackup failed with errors!

I tried manually to set the required information, but all attempts were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there has been a software update of **mysql** without running **mysql_upgrade**. This page size error also appears most likely when you re-start the database. Please run **mysql_upgrade** and see if the problem disappears.